# jQuery plugin to extend on() function doesn't accept "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousetrap

I'm writing a plugin to extend the **`on()`** function of jQuery to implement mousetrap.js

I should get from the function **`this`** and pass it to **`on()`**.

This is my code:

```
    $.fn.superon = function (keys, myfn) {
        $("body").on("click", this, function (e) {
            myfn();
        });
        Mousetrap.bind(keys, function () {
            myfn();
        });
    };
    $.fn.superoff = function (keys) {
        $("body").off(this);
        Mousetrap.unbind(keys);
    };
```

The problem is that if I use it the event is attached to all the elements and not only the one selected.

http://jsfiddle.net/zkLMX/1/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: One quick thing you should fix is `$("body").off('click', this);`

Answer (score 1):

1. You are missing event type `"click"` in `.off` function.
2. Second argument to `.on` function in your case has to be selector (what you are passing is jQuery object)

Following is the updated code

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.superon = function (selector, keys, myfn) {
        $("body").on("click", selector, function (e) {
            myfn();
        });
        Mousetrap.bind(keys, function () {
            myfn();
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.superoff = function (selector, keys) {
        $("body").off("click", selector);
        Mousetrap.unbind(keys);
        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);


$("#click").superon("#click", "a", function () {
    alert("hello");
    $("#click").superoff("a");
});

});

$("#click2").superon("#click2", "b", function () {
    alert("hello2");
    $("#click2").superoff("b");
});
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: I'm not sure that the plugin will always refer to an element with an ID. Your solution is not ok in this case.

Comment: @FezVrasta Agree, fixed the error. @devnull69 No it is not required that element `#click` should exist. It is required to exist to call `$('#click')` else for attaching event `.on` now it is not mandatory to exist.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, thanks for the suggestion of @devnull69.

```
 // on() with keyboard shortcut support
 $.fn.superon = function (selector, keys, myfn) {
   this.on("click", selector, function (e) {
     myfn();
   });
   Mousetrap.bind(keys, function () {
     myfn();
   });
   return this;
 };

 // off() with keyboard shortcut support
 $.fn.superoff = function (selector, keys) {
   this.off("click", selector);
   Mousetrap.unbind(keys);
   return this;
 };
```

In this way I will call this in the same way of how I would call the `on()` and `off()` functions.

Answer (score -2):

The second parameter to `.on()` is a selector string, not an element. You should just omit the second parameter and bind the click to `this` instead of `body`

```
$.fn.superon = function (keys, myfn) {
    this.on("click", function (e) {
        myfn();
    });
    Mousetrap.bind(keys, function () {
        myfn();
    });
};
$.fn.superoff = function (keys) {
    this.off("click");
    Mousetrap.unbind(keys);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zkLMX/4/

Comment: In this way it would not be fired if "this" is a dinamically added element, no?

Comment: You can only run methods (also from plug-ins) on already created elements. So if you want to use `.on()` on dynamically created elements, you'll have to add a `selector` as a string parameter to your plug-in call

Comment: got it, so I should use "this" instead of $("body") and a var selector as selector. thanks

Comment: Ok :-) but someone did and I'd like to understand why

Comment: Reasons for downvoting are 1. You can not attach event to dynamically added elements. What @FezVrasta has done has no problem in that way. 2. $(this) in line 2 is wasteful and degrades performance as `this` in this case is already a jQuery object. Go through [Signs of poorly written jQuery plugins](http://remysharp.com/2010/06/03/signs-of-a-poorly-written-jquery-plugin/)

Comment: The requirement to include dynamically added elements came up only after my answer. My answer will work perfectly if you call `.superon()` on existing elements. I corrected the `$(this)` part though

Comment: And the intention was not to present the OP with a perfectly rewritten plug-in. I leave this to the OP to investigate